# Laravel pagination returns different results when items per page change

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pagination

I'm working on complaint system and I've noticed that in my controller where I am getting my rows and I paginate them and order them I get different results when I change the number of items per page. First is 30 that works fine then 50 but when I change the `$data['results']` to 100 it suddenly returns some complaints that were not at the start of the page before.

Controller

```
$complaints = Complaint::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($data['results']);
```

I have vue component set up that just calls axios GET request with number taken from variable that holds how many items I want to have per page

The complaints that PHP returns are same when number of items per page is under 100 but after it gets to 100 or more suddenly there are around 8 new items that were not shown previously (at least not at the start of the first page which they should have been since its ordering it by created_at)

**Edit**

When I remove the orderBy part from the code it suddenly works normally but I've checked and all created_at fields in the DB are filled in without any NULL values

It could be that the problem is happening because a lot of them were imported from csv file and have almost identical created_at times with differences in ms and even then some have the same ms

**Edit 2**

I've checked the pagination object trough Vue devtools and all of them (when items per page is set to 30 and when it's set to 100) have the same created_at date even with ms matching that could be causing some trouble with getting them from DB properly

**Edit 3**

These are the queries:

paginate 30:

```
"select count(*) as aggregate from `complaints`"
"select * from `complaints` order by `created_at` desc limit 30 offset 0"
```

paginate 100:

```
"select count(*) as aggregate from `complaints`"
"select * from `complaints` order by `created_at` desc limit 100 offset 0"
```

Comment: check Queries which is call at controller at when 30, 50, 100 records... then share more details so I can helps to you... you can print query using "->toSql()"